# Recreating map in Scheme

Tags: scheme, map-function

Since my last post I went and asked a professor about Scheme and some good exercises I could do to familiarize myself with the language.

Here is one of the questions he e-mailed me that I just can't figure out:

> 1) Create a function that has the same behavior as `map`. Do not use `map` in your implementation.

As well as this:

> 2) Create a function that will transform the list `'(map func '(some list))` into a function invocation for the function you defined in step 1. If you evaluate the resulting code, it should have the effect of performing the *map* operation.

Any help I can get would be really helpful.

Comment: Yup that seems to be what I am looking for. Thank you! And I apologize that I couldn't find that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation: read the chapter "Functions that produce lists" then return to the program of implementing `map`. After reading the chapter I think you can solve it.

http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html#%28part._sec~3alist-produce%29

Comment: Just finished reading through that section. Thanks for pointing it out! I learned a lot!